# Context with React Native hooks returns empty object/array on async function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, async-await, react-hooks, react-context

I have been battling this issue for some time now and I can't seem to figure out how to solve it.

On my homescreen I fetch the user coordinates and an array of cinemas.  The Cinemas array contains coordinates for each cinema, which I use with the user coordinates to calculate the distance from the user to the cinema.

Fetching and storing the cinemas in the cinemaContext is fine and working, but once I run the function that calculates the distance, the cinema object in context is empty.
The distance calculation adds a distance value to each cinema in the array and returns the new array.

The weird thing is the cinema context object is empty when I try.  Then if I edit something in the cinemaContext or inside the getUserCoordinates function and navigate to the cinema overview screen, then the cinemas are there with the distance value.

It must be something with the loading sequence or async functionality, because the code is "working", but does not seem to populate the context at the right time or overwrite it with empty value.

I should add that I use the cinemas array on another screen, where I get access to it like this:

```
const { state } = useContext(Context)
```

Home.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, StatusBar, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import { Context } from "../context/CinemaContext";

const Home = ({ navigation }) => {

  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);
  const { state, updateCinemas, getCinemas } = useContext(Context)

  // Fetch user coordinates and call updateCinemas with the coordinates and cinemas 
  const getUserCoordinates = async (cinemas) => {
    try {
      const granted = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
      
      if (granted) {
        let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});

        await updateCinemas(cinemas, location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude)
        
      } else {
        throw new Error("Location permission not granted");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setErrorMsg(e)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (state.cinemas.length === 0) {
      getCinemas();
    }
    getUserCoordinates(state.cinemas);
  }, []);

  if (!state.cinemas) {
    return <ActivityIndicator size="large" style={{ marginTop: 200 }} />
  }

  return ( Some views ..)
```

CinemaContext.js

```
import dataContext from "./DataContext";
import _ from "lodash";
import { computeDistance } from "../helpers/utils";


const cinemaReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "add_error":
      return { ...state, errorMessage: action.payload };
    case "get_cinemas":
      return { ...state, cinemas: action.payload };
    case "update_cinemas":
      return { ...state, cinemas: action.payload };
    default:
      return state
  }
};

const getCinemas = dispatch => async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      "url-to-cinemas-array",
      { mode: "no-cors" })
    const cinemas = await response.json();
    dispatch({
      type: "get_cinemas",
      payload: cinemas
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: "add_error",
      payload: "Something went wrong with the cinemas"
    })
  }
}

const updateCinemas = (dispatch) => {

  return async (cinemas, referenceLat, referenceLong) => {
    
    const cinemasWithDistance = cinemas.map(cinema => {
      return {
        ...cinema,
        distance: computeDistance([cinema.geo.latitude, cinema.geo.longitude], [referenceLat, referenceLong]) // Calculate the distance
        
      };
    });    
    const orderedCinemas = _.orderBy(cinemasWithDistance, 'distance');
    dispatch({ type: "update_cinemas", payload: orderedCinemas });
  }
}

export const { Context, Provider } = dataContext(
  cinemaReducer,
  { updateCinemas, getCinemas },
  { cinemas: [], errorMessage: '' }
);
```

DataContext.js

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';

export default (reducer, actions, defaultValue) => {
  const Context = React.createContext();

  const Provider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, defaultValue);

    const boundActions = {};
    for (let key in actions) {
      boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch);
    }

    return (
      <Context.Provider value={{ state, ...boundActions }}>
        {children}
      </Context.Provider>
    );
  };

  return { Context, Provider };
};
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import RootStackNavigator from "./src/navigation/RootStackNavigator";
import { Provider } from "./src/context/CinemaContext";

export default function App() {

  return (
    <Provider>
      <RootStackNavigator />
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `state.cinemas` is still empty when you call `getUserCoordinates(state.cinemas);` so `"update_cinemas"` action will run with an empty array, overwriting the cinemas array updated previously by `"get_cinemas"`. You can verify this by adding `console.log('state.cinemas.length: ', state.cinemas.length);` before the `getUserCoordinates` call.

One solution to this I think would be to call `getUserCoordinates` in a separate `useEffect` that depends on `state.cinemas` array (so that it runs again every time `state.cinemas` changes):

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (state.cinemas.length === 0) {
    getCinemas();
  }
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  if (state.cinemas.length === 0) return; // cinemas not retrieved yet
  if (typeof state.cinemas[0].distance !== undefined) return; // distance already computed
  getUserCoordinates(state.cinemas);
}, [state.cinemas]);
```

Comment: Ah very nice!  I will try it out.
I actually managed to fix it by adding a "sorted" value to the cinemaContext and then doing a check like this:


  useEffect(() => {
    if (state.cinemas.length === 0) {
      getCinemas();
    }
    
    if (state.cinemas.length > 0 && !state.sorted) {
      getUserCoordinates(state.cinemas);      
    }
  }, [state.cinemas]);


I will try your solution too, because it seems cleaner

Comment: Awesome, it works! :)
You are right regarding the issue.  I think your solution makes sense, because its possible to re-fetch the cinemas or even display error messages to the user if something went wrong.

Thank you very much!